# MAP estimator of Z=X/Y estimating X

Tags: estimation

The probabilities are given
$$pdf(y)=\lambda_ye^{-\lambda_y y}, y\geq0$$
$$pdf(x)=\lambda_xe^{-\lambda_x x}, x\geq0$$
I have the observation such that $z=x/y$. I want to estimate $x$. First, I found 
$$pdf(z)={\lambda_x\lambda_y\over{(\lambda_x {z}}+\lambda_y)^2}$$. I know that MAP estimator  of $x$ is
$$\hat x=arg[max_{\theta}(Pr(x|z))]$$
$$Pr(x|z)={pdf(z|x)pdf(x)\over pdf(z)}$$
So,
$$pdf(z|x)={\lambda_x\lambda_y\over{(\lambda_x {x \over y}}+\lambda_y)^2}$$
right? So I just maximize
$$pdf(z|x)pdf(x)$$
right?
Sorry for notation

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure whether the following equation holds: $$pdf(z|x) = \frac{\lambda_x \lambda_y}{(\lambda_x \frac{x}{y} + \lambda_y)^2}$$

It seems that:
$$\begin{align}
pdf_Z(z|x)dz &= P(Z = z|X = x) \\
&= P(\frac{X}{Y} = z|X=x) \\
&=P(Y = \frac{x}{z}|X = x)
\end{align}$$

According to your pdf of Z, it seems that X and Y are assumed independent, so:
$$\begin{align}
pdf(z|x)dz &= P(Y = \frac{x}{z}|X = x) \\
&= P(Y = \frac{x}{z})\\ 
&= pdf_Y(\frac{x}{z})dy \\
&= pdf_Y(\frac{x}{z})(\bigl\lvert-\frac{x}{z^2}\bigr\rvert dz)\\
\\
pdf(z|x)&=\frac{x}{z^2}\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2\frac{x}{z}}
\end{align}$$